ros2_control_node missing all hardware interfaces
I have a ros2_control setup for a real robot but, when I launch my files, I get this output:
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/flamethrower/.ros/log/2024-08-28-19-26-23-251791-robot-7828
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [7833]
[robot_state_publisher-1] Parsing robot urdf xml string.
[robot_state_publisher-1] Link FL_wheel had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-1] Link FR_wheel had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-1] Link RL_wheel had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-1] Link RR_wheel had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-1] Link chassis had 1 children
[robot_state_publisher-1] Link laser_frame had 0 children
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1724865984.065846446] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment FL_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1724865984.066144683] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment FR_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1724865984.066194109] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment RL_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1724865984.066223145] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment RR_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1724865984.066246923] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1724865984.066272367] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment chassis
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1724865984.066295570] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment laser_frame
[INFO] [ros2_control_node-2]: process started with pid [7894]
[INFO] [spawner.py-3]: process started with pid [7896]
[INFO] [spawner.py-4]: process started with pid [7898]
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO] [1724865989.669762906] [DiffDriveArduino]: Configuring...
[ros2_control_node-2] [INFO] [1724865989.672711054] [DiffDriveArduino]: Finished Configuration
[ros2_control_node-2] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
[ros2_control_node-2]   what():  Wrong state or command interface configuration.
[ros2_control_node-2] missing state interfaces:
[ros2_control_node-2] ' FL_wheel_joint/velocity '   ' FL_wheel_joint/position ' ' FR_wheel_joint/velocity ' ' FR_wheel_joint/position ' ' RL_wheel_joint/velocity ' ' RL_wheel_joint/position ' ' RR_wheel_joint/velocity ' ' RR_wheel_joint/position ' 
[ros2_control_node-2] missing command interfaces:
[ros2_control_node-2] ' FL_wheel_joint/velocity '   ' FR_wheel_joint/velocity ' ' RL_wheel_joint/velocity ' ' RR_wheel_joint/velocity ' 
[spawner.py-4] [INFO] [1724865990.742294415] [spawner_diff_cont]: Waiting for /controller_manager services
[spawner.py-3] [INFO] [1724865990.819649414] [spawner_joint_broad]: Waiting for /controller_manager services
[ERROR] [ros2_control_node-2]: process has died [pid 7894, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/foxy/lib/controller_manager/ros2_control_node --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params_cw7q52ou --params-file /home/flamethrower/robot_ws/install/robot/share/robot/config/my_controllers.yaml'].
[spawner.py-4] [INFO] [1724865992.784568230] [spawner_diff_cont]: Waiting for /controller_manager services
[spawner.py-3] [INFO] [1724865992.866697466] [spawner_joint_broad]: Waiting for /controller_manager services
[spawner.py-4] [INFO] [1724865994.832067367] [spawner_diff_cont]: Waiting for /controller_manager services
[spawner.py-3] [INFO] [1724865994.918851637] [spawner_joint_broad]: Waiting for /controller_manager services
[spawner.py-4] [INFO] [1724865996.879308967] [spawner_diff_cont]: Waiting for /controller_manager services
[spawner.py-3] [INFO] [1724865996.969542750] [spawner_joint_broad]: Waiting for /controller_manager services
[spawner.py-4] [INFO] [1724865998.930070373] [spawner_diff_cont]: Waiting for /controller_manager services
[spawner.py-3] [INFO] [1724865999.021213885] [spawner_joint_broad]: Waiting for /controller_manager services
[spawner.py-4] [ERROR] [1724866000.777110112] [spawner_diff_cont]: Controller manager not available
[spawner.py-3] [ERROR] [1724866000.861784019] [spawner_joint_broad]: Controller manager not available
[ERROR] [spawner.py-4]: process has died [pid 7898, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/foxy/lib/controller_manager/spawner.py diff_cont --ros-args'].
[ERROR] [spawner.py-3]: process has died [pid 7896, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/foxy/lib/controller_manager/spawner.py joint_broad --ros-args'].

It says all the state and command interfaces are missing, but they're clearly defined in my ros2_control.xacro file:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <ros2_control name="RobotSystem" type="system">
        <hardware>
            <plugin>diffdrive_arduino/DiffDriveArduino</plugin>
            <param name="left_wheel_name">FL_wheel_joint RL_wheel_joint</param>
            <param name="right_wheel_name">FR_wheel_joint RR_wheel_joint</param>
            <param name="loop_rate">30</param>
            <param name="device">/dev/ttyACM0</param>
            <param name="baud_rate">57600</param>
            <param name="timeout">1000</param>
            <param name="enc_counts_per_rev">3436</param>
        </hardware>
        <joint name="FL_wheel_joint">
            <command_interface name="velocity">
                <param name="min">-10</param>
                <param name="max">10</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="FR_wheel_joint">
            <command_interface name="velocity">
                <param name="min">-10</param>
                <param name="max">10</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="RL_wheel_joint">
            <command_interface name="velocity">
                <param name="min">-10</param>
                <param name="max">10</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>
        <joint name="RR_wheel_joint">
            <command_interface name="velocity">
                <param name="min">-10</param>
                <param name="max">10</param>
            </command_interface>
            <state_interface name="velocity"/>
            <state_interface name="position"/>
        </joint>
    </ros2_control>
    
    <gazebo>
        <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros2_control.so" name="gazebo_ros2_control">
            <parameters>$(find robot)/config/my_controllers.yaml</parameters>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>

</robot>

These are the other relevant files, in case they're useful:
robot.launch.py:
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory


from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription, TimerAction
from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch.substitutions import Command
from launch.actions import RegisterEventHandler
from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessStart

from launch_ros.actions import Node



def generate_launch_description():


    # Include the robot_state_publisher launch file, provided by our own package. Force sim time to be enabled
    # !!! MAKE SURE YOU SET THE PACKAGE NAME CORRECTLY !!!

    package_name='robot' #<--- CHANGE ME

    rsp = IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(
                    get_package_share_directory(package_name),'launch','rsp.launch.py'
                )]), launch_arguments={'use_sim_time': 'false', 'use_ros2_control': 'true'}.items()
    )




    robot_description = Command(['ros2 param get --hide-type /robot_state_publisher robot_description'])

    controller_params_file = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(package_name),'config','my_controllers.yaml')

    controller_manager = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="ros2_control_node",
        parameters=[{'robot_description': robot_description},
                    controller_params_file]
    )

    delayed_controller_manager = TimerAction(period=3.0, actions=[controller_manager])

    diff_drive_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner.py",
        arguments=["diff_cont"],
    )
    
    delayed_diff_drive_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessStart(
            target_action=controller_manager,
            on_start=[diff_drive_spawner],
        )
    )

    joint_broad_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner.py",
        arguments=["joint_broad"],
    )
    
    delayed_joint_broad_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessStart(
            target_action=controller_manager,
            on_start=[joint_broad_spawner],
        )
    )



    # Launch them all!
    return LaunchDescription([
        rsp,
        delayed_controller_manager,
        delayed_diff_drive_spawner,
        delayed_joint_broad_spawner
    ])

rsp.launch.py:
import os

from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory

from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.substitutions import LaunchConfiguration, Command
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch_ros.actions import Node

import xacro


def generate_launch_description():

    # Check if we're told to use sim time
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')
    use_ros2_control = LaunchConfiguration('use_ros2_control')

    # Process the URDF file
    pkg_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('robot'))
    xacro_file = os.path.join(pkg_path,'description','robot.urdf.xacro')
    # robot_description_config = xacro.process_file(xacro_file).toxml()
    robot_description_config = Command(['xacro ', xacro_file, ' use_ros2_control:=', use_ros2_control, ' sim_mode:=', use_sim_time])
    
    # Create a robot_state_publisher node
    params = {'robot_description': robot_description_config, 'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}
    node_robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[params]
    )


    # Launch!
    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_sim_time',
            default_value='false',
            description='Use sim time if true'),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_ros2_control',
            default_value='true',
            description='Use ros2_control if true'),

        node_robot_state_publisher
    ])

robot.urdf.xacro:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro"  name="robot">

    <xacro:arg name="use_ros2_control" default="true"/>
    <xacro:arg name="sim_mode" default="false"/>

    <xacro:include filename="robot_core.xacro" />
    <xacro:include filename="ros2_control.xacro"/>
    <xacro:include filename="lidar.xacro"/>

</robot>

robot_core.xacro:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <xacro:include filename="inertial_macros.xacro"/>

    <material name="gray">
        <color rgba="0.3 0.3 0.3 1"/>
    </material>

    <material name="black">
        <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
    </material>

    <material name="blue">
        <color rgba="0 0 0.6 1"/>
    </material>

    <link name="base_link">

    </link>

    <joint name="chassis_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="chassis"/>
        <origin xyz="-0.1 0 0"/>
    </joint>
        
    <link name="chassis">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0.175 0 0.715"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.35 0.35 1.4"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="gray"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0.175 0 0.715"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.35 0.35 1.4"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:inertial_box mass="1" x="0.35" y="0.35" z="1.4">
            <origin xyz="0.2 0 0.075" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </xacro:inertial_box>
    </link>
    
    <gazebo reference="chassis">
        <material>Gazebo/Gray</material>
    </gazebo>

    <joint name="FL_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="FL_wheel"/>
        <origin xyz="0.225 0.185 0.05" rpy="-${pi/2} 0 0"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="FL_wheel">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="black"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:inertial_cylinder mass="0.1" length="0.02" radius="0.05">
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </xacro:inertial_cylinder>
    </link>
    
    <gazebo reference="FL_wheel">
        <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
    </gazebo>

    <joint name="FR_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="FR_wheel"/>
        <origin xyz="0.225 -0.185 0.05" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    </joint>
    
    <link name="FR_wheel">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="black"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:inertial_cylinder mass="0.1" length="0.02" radius="0.05">
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </xacro:inertial_cylinder>
    </link>
    
    <gazebo reference="FR_wheel">
        <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
    </gazebo>
    
    <joint name="RL_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="RL_wheel"/>
        <origin xyz="-0.075 0.185 0.05" rpy="-${pi/2} 0 0"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    </joint>
    
    <link name="RL_wheel">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="black"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:inertial_cylinder mass="0.1" length="0.02" radius="0.05">
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </xacro:inertial_cylinder>
    </link>
    
    <gazebo reference="RL_wheel">
        <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
    </gazebo>

    <joint name="RR_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="RR_wheel"/>
        <origin xyz="-0.075 -0.185 0.05" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    </joint>
    
    <link name="RR_wheel">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="black"/>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        <xacro:inertial_cylinder mass="0.1" length="0.02" radius="0.05">
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        </xacro:inertial_cylinder>
    </link>
    
    <gazebo reference="RR_wheel">
        <material>Gazebo/Black</material>
    </gazebo>

</robot>

my_controllers.yaml:
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 30
    #use_sim_time: true

    diff_cont:
      type: diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController

    joint_broad:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

diff_cont:
  ros__parameters:

    publish_rate: 50.0

    base_frame_id: base_link

    left_wheel_names: ["FL_wheel_joint", "RL_wheel_joint"]
    right_wheel_names: ["FR_wheel_joint", "RR_wheel_joint"]
    wheel_separation: 0.35
    wheel_radius: 0.05

    use_stamped_vel: false

    # open_loop: false    

    wheels_per_side: 2

I'm following the Articulated Robotics tutorials, and Josh Newans' package does work. I've compared both but haven't managed to find the root of the issue. I've tried commenting out my second wheel names (as I have 4 instead of 2), using more similar naming and carefully checking the syntax, with no result.

First of all, please update from Foxy to a distro which hasn't reached EOL already.
The error message indicates that the hardware component has not exported the expected interfaces. Check the export_state_interfaces and export_command_interfaces methods, see this guide (not available for foxy).

The thing is I'm using a Raspberry Pi, so i can only use Gazebo11 with Foxy. But is it not an error in the files, then? (I can't seem to access the link)

I fixed the link. Why you need gazebo? I don't see that in your urdf

https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/How-To-Guides/Installing-on-Raspberry-Pi.html

I need it because I'm running robot simulations apart from controlling the real robot for testing, but I've figured it out now. It was grouping the wheel names I put divided by spaces in a single string so it published the state and hardware interfaces for those, but not for the wheels described in the file. I modified the DiffDriveArduino plugin so that it takes 4 of them instead of 2 and I'll see if it works with my physical robot.
